# CMake Prevent Need for Inclusion of Precise Header Location

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-language

I have the following directory structure:

```
Project
  |  
  |-CMakeLists.txt

Library
  |
  |-LibProjectA
  |   |-CMakeLists.txt
  |   |-src
  |      |-SomeHeader0.h
  |-LibProjectB
  |   |-CMakeLists.txt
  |   |-src
  |      |-SomeHeader1.h
  |-LibProjectC
      |-CMakeLists.txt
      |-src
         |-SomeHeader2.h

OpenSourceProject
  |
  |-CMakeLists.txt
  |-src
     |-SomeOpenSourceHeader.h
```

Wherein `Project` includes the statically linked library `LibProjectA` in the `Library` directory.  `LibProjectA` depends on `LibProjectB`. `LibProjectB` depends on `LibProjectC`.  `LibProjectA`, `LibProjectB`, and `LibProjectC` all utilize the `OpenSourceProject` and `LibProjectC` specifically requires access to `SomeOpenSourceHeader.h`.

Whenever I perform an `add_subdirectory` on `LibProjectC`, I am forced to provide a precise path specifying where `SomeOpenSourceHeader.h` is.  Even if this is in the `CMakeLists.txt` within the top level `Project` directory. Is there some way that by merely performing an `add_subdirectory` on the `CMakeLists.txt` in the `OpenSourceProject`, the path can be provided such that files therein can automatically be recognized elsewhere in the code and that the target project doesn't need to have any knowledge about the open source library used at a much lower level.

All libraries are statically linked.

Comment: What include paths are you setting?  How are you setting said include paths?

Comment: Currently, if `LibProjectC` requires access to `SomeOpenSourceHeader.h` I would have to do `target_include_directories( ${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ../../OpenSourceProject/src`.  This is precisely what I want to avoid.  If there is already an `add_subdirectory( ../../OpenSourceProject build_osp)`, why should I have also specify the precise location of the header? When using open source libraries like `fmt` this is somehow avoided.

Comment: If `OpenSourceProject` sets include paths properly, `target_link_libraries` should handle that for you.  If it doesn't, send a patch upstream so that include paths (and other flags) are set properly on the project and will propagate to dependents.

Comment: Thank you! That worked.  I created a MWE based on the use of `target_include_directories` instead of `include_directories`.